# OAuth token endpoint failure on AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord login: BadRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, discord, aspnet-contrib

I'm currently running into an `OAuth token endpoint failure` using the `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord` library during login after Discord has authenticated me and returned to my `ASP.NET` site. The code for authentication is detailed below, with full error logs and relevant controller, with all this running in a docker container. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The exact error is `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord.DiscordAuthenticationHandler[4]: Error from RemoteAuthentication: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest`. This occurs after visiting `http://.../login`, which returns to the default `/signin-discord` URL of the library, with an expected parameter of `code` in `/signin-discord?code=....`.

Authentication Scheme when creating WebApplication:

[image: Authentication scheme]

MVC Controller:

[image: Authentication controller]

Error Logs:

[image: Error logs]

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly fixed by putting `app.UseAuthentication();` below `app.UseRouting();` and above `app.UseAuthorization();` and `app.UseEndpoints();`

Comment: I got the same error by just missing the `app.UseAuthentication()` invoke ;-)